# Sistema de notificações

Tags: php

Boa noite,

Eu tenho um sistema de seguidores, sistema de comentários, gostos e posts e preciso de criar agora um sistema de notificações em que o utilizador que estiver `logado` receba notificações da parte dos utilizadores que está a seguir como por exemplo:

João começou a seguir-te
João comentou x post
João publicou um post
João gostou de x post

O meu problema e que nunca fiz algo parecido e não sei por onde começar em termos de criação de tabelas necessárias, preciso da vossa ajuda para ter uma ideia simples de fazer este tipo de sistema.

Comment: duplicada não foi eu que publiquei essa pergunta

Comment: TABELA "acao" 2 CAMPOS "Usuario" - "qual_acao" : se o usuario clicou em seguir, no mesmo script vc faz outro insert na tabela acao tipo INSERT into ACAO (usuario, acao)  VALUES ($usuario, comecou a seguir $outrousuario). Creio que basta algo do tipo.